# Default document in Google App Engine / Java

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it possible to specify the equivalent of a default document for directories in Google App Engine for Java so that navigating to that directory automatically redirects to its index.html for example, if it contains one?

Comment: Are you talking about static files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the welcome-files section in your yaml file to the appropriate file names.  See the documentation here http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml.html#The_Welcome_File_List